# Load balancer and Containers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-ecs

I need feedback and advice.
I'm building a split platform on two different servers (one for the front end and the other for the backend). The two parties communicate via API.

The problem: the frontend party makes a request to almost every user action in order to do tracking on event on the backend side. But the requests are high and the free tier ec2 instance can't keep up. So I thought of implementing a load balancer on the ec2 instance that shares the load with the containers.

Is it possible to implement containers and load balancers using the free plan? Do you think it is a feasible solution and that it solves the problem? Do you recommend any other solution?

Comment: The container services aren't part of free tier, some [Load Balancer Capacity units](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?nc1=h_ls&all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&all-free-tier.q=load%2Bbalancing&all-free-tier.q_operator=AND) are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free tier is not meant to be used for development of "heavy" applications. It is  for you to basically learn core AWS services and do some small prototyping.

But if you consider ECS, only **ECS EC2 launch** type is covered by free tier, because you are only paying for instances (Fargate is not free). If you want to use two t2.micro instances for your ECS tasks, the free tier will only cover **about 15 days** of their usage, i.e. 750 hours / 24 / 2 instance.

So with or without a balancer, you are pretty much limited to one t2.micro per month. So you either should consider paying for the AWS services that your application is using, or make it "less-heavy" to work well on t2.micro.